# How to upload to AWS S3 directly from browser using a pre-signed URL instead of credentials?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We'd like to use Javascript AWS SDK to upload files to S3, but without using credentials at all.
Uploading using credentials works, but we cannot generate an AWS IAM user for each of our app users (or should we?)

Therefore, similar to using GET, we'd like the server to generate a pre-signed URL, send it to browser, and have the browser upload to that URL.

However, there are no examples on how to accomplish this.
Also, if not setting a credential, even before making the upload to S3 request, the SDK errors with

```
code: "CredentialsError"
message: "No credentials to load"
```

The JS SDK docs mention this, so it seems it would be possible:

```
Pre-signing a putObject (asynchronously)
var params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key'};
    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function (err, url) {
      console.log('The URL is', url);
});
```

Comment: what is key here ?? Moreover without ACCESS_ID_KEY and SECRET_KEY how r u requesting server for signed URL ?

Comment: https://fineuploader-s3-client-demo.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Answer (score 27):

Quiet the old question but it did help me a bit to get it finally done.
My solution is based on PHP and JavaScript with jQuery.

I have the entire solution nicely wrapped at https://github.com/JoernBerkefeld/s3SignedUpload but here are the essentials:

api.php:

```
<?php
require_once '/server/path/to/aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\Common\Aws;

$BUCKET = "my-bucket";
$CONFIG = "path-to-iam-credentials-file-relative-to-root.php"

function getSignedUrl($filename, $mime) {
    $S3 = Aws::factory( $CONFIG )->get('S3');
    if(!$filename) {
        return $this->error('filename missing');
    }
    if(!$mime) {
        return $this->error('mime-type missing');
    }
    $final_filename = $this->get_file_name($filename);
    try {
        $signedUrl = $S3->getCommand('PutObject', array(
            'Bucket' => $BUCKET,
            'Key' => $this->folder . $final_filename,
            'ContentType' => $mime,
            'Body'        => '',
            'ContentMD5'  => false
        ))->createPresignedUrl('+30 minutes');
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
    $signedUrl .= '&Content-Type='.urlencode($mime);
    return $signedUrl;
}


echo getSignedUrl($_GET['filename'],$_GET['mimetype']);
```

please make sure to **add user authentication** to your api.php. Else everyone who knows the path to that file could upload files to your bucket.

credentials.inc.php:

```
<?php
return array(
    'includes' => array('_aws'),
    'services' => array(
        'default_settings' => array(
            'params' => array(
                'key'    => 'MY-ACCESS-KEY',
                'secret' => 'MY-SECRECT',
                'region'  => 'eu-west-1' // set to your region
            )
        )
    )
);
```

client.js:

```
$("input[type=file]").onchange = function () {
    for (var file, i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        file = this.files[i];
        $.ajax({
            url : s3presignedApiUri,
            data: 'file='+ file.name + '&mime=' + file.type,
            type : "GET",
            dataType : "json",
            cache : false,
        })
        .done(function(s3presignedUrl) {
            $.ajax({
                url : s3presignedUrl,
                type : "PUT",
                data : file,
                dataType : "text",
                cache : false,
                contentType : file.type,
                processData : false
            })
            .done(function(){
                console.info('YEAH', s3presignedUrl.split('?')[0].substr(6));
            }
            .fail(function(){
                console.error('damn...');
            }
        })
    }
};
```

s3 cors settings (PUT & OPTIONS are actually needed, but cannot enable OPTIONS directly...):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: What goes into get_file_name()?

Answer (score 18):

If you're not using jQuery, this is the minimal you need on the front end:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('PUT', signedUrl, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', signedUrlContentType);
xhr.onload = () => {
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    // success!
  }
};
xhr.onerror = () => {
  // error...
};
xhr.send(file); // `file` is a File object here
```

See File object docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Then you can add your upload progress as usual:

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {
  if (event.lengthComputable) {
    var percent = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100)
    console.log(percent);
  }
};
```

Comment: After trying soo many different ways, this worked first time. Thanks Scott

Answer (score 6):

In project, on what I am working right now I have file uploads from client directly to S3, in my case it works in few steps:

1. request pre-signed form with settings for upload, from server (it is signed on a server, because I can not pass access keys to the client, and also I need to apply some limitations to upload)
2. upload file to S3 using XHR2 (for old browsers you can use hack with hidden iframe or browser plugins like flash)

There is main code parts from it: https://gist.github.com/zxbodya/3cdabd9172bcc89f8ac5

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's customary to show the most relevant parts of the code needed in your answer, in order to save the search on the web.

Answer (score 2):

Please add `ACL` and `ContentType`, it'll make it work.

```
const param = {
      Bucket: 'Bucket',
      Key: 'fiileName',
      ACL: 'public-read',
      ContentType: 'fileType'
    };
s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', param, function (err, url) {
         console.log('The URL is', url);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate Url

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
   endpoint: 's3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com',   // Put you region
   accessKeyId: 'AKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXA6U',       // Put you accessKeyId
   secretAccessKey: 'kzFHoXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXssoGp',   // Put you accessKeyId
   Bucket: 'Bucket-Name',         // Put your bucket name
   signatureVersion: 'v4',
   region: 'ap-south-1'           // Put you region
});

const getSingedUrlforPut = async () => {
const params = {
    Bucket: 'Bucket-Name',
    Key: '317ec11af14a46b89f400bcf8f9fff1222.pdf',
    Expires: 60 * 5
  };
try {
    const url = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, (err, url) => {
        err ? reject(err) : resolve(url);
      });
    });
    console.log(url)
  } catch (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
}
getSingedUrlforPut()
```

Upload file Via ajax

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("", fileInput.files[0], "director_pan_af8ef2d261c46877f95038622c96e7c0.pdf");
var settings = {
  "url": "https://sme-testing.s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/317ec11af14a46b89f400bcf8f9fff1222.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIXXXXXXXXXXXX6U%2F20200525%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200525T083419Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=ea063731d7d043b62d0dc7c0984f4d5792c7f7f41e9ffb52a97d62adadcef422&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host",
  "method": "PUT",
  "timeout": 0,
  "processData": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "contentType": false,
  "data": form
};
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest two approaches:

1- You could generate a pre-signed form in your app, with one credential

See doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTForms.html

2- You could use web identity federation and use login with google, facebook or amazon:

See doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-configuring-wif.html

Playground: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/08/the-aws-web-identity-federation-playground.html

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this cleaner approach, via github:

If you already have a presigned URL generated for the browser, you can simply send an XHR request with that URL and the payload to upload to S3. The SDK would not be required to do this. A jQuery example below:

```
$.ajax({
  url: presignedUrl, // the presigned URL
  type: 'PUT',
  data: 'data to upload into URL',
  success: function() { console.log('Uploaded data successfully.'); }
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more. I mean how will u upload without AWS S3 SDK ? You need to verify credentials r8?

Comment: No you don't have to verify credentials because you use a presign an url on your server (that has knowledge of your key and secret) and send this signed url to the client. The client then uses this presignedUrl to upload the file.

Comment: When I try this I keep getting `[Exception... "Access to restricted URI denied"  code: "1012" nsresult: "0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)"  location: "<unknown>` I am assuming it has to do with some CORS policy but do not know how to fix it at the moment did you run into this? (Using firefox 31.4.0)