# How to upload file to aws s3 using xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

How can I upload file to s3 using xmlhttprequest. I tried following way but I got error like

> 'Anonymous access is forbidden for this operation'.

Here is my code:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('PUT', "https://region.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/");
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Amz-ACL', 'public-read');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
xhr.send({
    file: file,
    type: 'image/png',
    name: "myfile_9898_0",
    acl: 'public-read',
    AWSAccessKeyId: 'aws key',
    AWSSecreKeyId: 'scret_key'
});
```

Is there anything wrong with this code?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you configured CORS for (POST,PUT) as allowmethods on the bucket?

Comment: Yeah, i already configured  CORS for (POST,PUT). but i am getting following response like ' Anonymous access is forbidden for this operation'

Comment: this [link](https://gist.github.com/joaoffcosta/5729398) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

you spelled SecretKey wrong.

however, anyone viewing this page (assuming it's in a html page) can steal your credentials! it's a Really Bad Idea to put secretKey anywhere - you're better to generate a 'pre-signed key' on the server with your secret. You'll also need CORS set up on your server to allow the cross-post.

Comment: related question how to do this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531114/how-to-upload-to-aws-s3-directly-from-browser-using-a-pre-signed-url-instead-of?rq=1