# AWS S3 PUT request with presigned URL not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I  am using lambda to generate presigned singature to upload files to a S3 bucket. The signature returned by lambda works when I use it with Postman/CURL . However, when I try a PUT request from my program it attaches localhost to the presigned URL. I am using IIS on my local computer as the web server.
Could it be something related to IIS configuration ? Or Am I doing something wrong in the code or the app configuration itself?

http://localhost/admin/%22https://sky-testwebsite-upload.s3.amazonaws.com/myfiletoupload.txt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Date=20190328T231808Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Security-Token=FQoGZXIvYXdzEJH%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaDHkQ6M3FyxPqcLENgSLzAUmW1nKDxcQt29OwkBhwPYnGk1GTBXwfMVgGJ1DfeATPyg6QZyxgB02hdPYPFNogxmZ0g4g6EG2mGQrqYAfsLaWJtwyOZU4lS3eQCNlevwjGRqEPehhrfQD8kD5keqiagrA5%2FCAXETN9dSW%2FwQD9%2B%2FOWnBhUTPaHncDt9cRNtm6G64u8htrG9Yzo3d%2FylbbCtEKYAirbrHBOLOzzcq%2FwZWj%2FQ9eq13qiXFYAqZEKiRpl1EPCNZy8dLywOYI0fyatzyf%2FBo5aXO%2BihFNHIfHIO4rpve8KMlvkNGtedsoeUXXP5GJi6vyIRm%2BOKSQH%2BpP8JXyiGqfXkBQ%3D%3D&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAYG7KDJKY75ML2HOH%2F20190328%2Fap-southeast-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=6280eb6f7f2c3cc26ff32ec5a4f542eb1f5a495f2e2efba6006445fe16d4c3e7%22

My code is below:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('PUT', preSignedURL);
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if(xhr.readyState === 4){
    if(xhr.status === 200){
      alert('File Ready to n upload. xhr.status: ' + xhr.status + 'xhrstatustext:' +xhr.statusText);

    }
    else{

      alert('Could not upload file.');
    }
  }
};
xhr.send(file);
```

Comment: This related answer may answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531114/how-to-upload-to-aws-s3-directly-from-browser-using-a-pre-signed-url-instead-of?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out myself. The URL returned by the lambda function was not formatted correctly. All I had to do was to remove the quotes from the first and last and after that my file was uploaded to S3.

var preSignedURL = preSignedURL.substring(1, preSignedURL.length-1);

Cheers!

Comment: You probably actually need to `JSON.parse()` the value instead of just removing the quotes.  If you are not doing that, then you have a potentially fragile, payload-sensitive solution that may break later.