# Prevent Javascript adding metadata on File Upload to S3

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

Basically I am willing to upload files directly to S3 via browser i.e without any web server acting as a middle-ware or proxy like this.

[image]

So I am generating pre-signed URL using boto3 library like this:

```
def put_url(self, key):
    url = self.client.generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod="put_object",
        Params={
            "Bucket": "visweswaran",
            "Key": key
        }
    )
    return url
```

and this returns a pre-signed URL which is completely fine. I am using JQuery to make ajax PUT request to the S3 to upload my file.

```
                let file_data = document.getElementById("file_data").files[0];
                var form = new FormData();
                form.append("", file_data, "test.txt");
                var settings = {
                  "url": url,
                  "method": "PUT",
                  "timeout": 0,
                  "processData": false,
                  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
                  "contentType": "text/plain",
                  "beforeSend": function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment');},
                  "data": form
                };
                $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
                  location.reload();
                });
```

The file gets uploaded to the S3 successfully via browser. But when I open the file I see strange meta data getting added to the top of the file like this,

> -----------------------------33057860671031084693134041830 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"
>
> test.txt
> -----------------------------33057860671031084693134041830 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"
> Content-Type: text/plain

I have also tried a more formal solution like Pluploader (https://www.plupload.com/) and I am facing the same problem. I would like somebody to point me in the right direction to fix it. Ant help is much appreciated.

**References:**

1. https://softwareontheroad.com/aws-s3-secure-direct-upload/
2. [How to upload to AWS S3 directly from browser using a pre-signed URL instead of credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531114/how-to-upload-to-aws-s3-directly-from-browser-using-a-pre-signed-url-instead-of)

**Working Solution**

I have tested with a video and you don't need a form. Just send the data directly

```
let video = document.getElementById("video_file").files[0];
var settings = {
    "url": url,
    "method": "PUT",
    "timeout": 0,
    "processData": false,
    "data": video
};
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    location.reload();
});
```

Comment: I recommend using POST instead of PUT to upload files from browser. You can use `generate_presigned_post` instead to generate required value of the fields for the frontend form. Here is a great [tutorial](https://blog.webiny.com/upload-files-to-aws-s3-using-pre-signed-post-data-and-a-lambda-function-7a9fb06d56c1) of how to do it step by step.

Comment: Could you try sending the PUT request without using formData at all?
The `data` attribute would have the reference of `file_data`, and the content-type while the signing  and sending (ajax) can be `ContentType: 'binary/octet-stream'`.

Comment: What happens if you remove `"mimeType": "multipart/form-data",` and `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment');` ?

Comment: @FelixKling I have removed the mimeType and I am seeing the same thing
-----------------------------261461442633876784451364777288
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried uploading a `txt` file with a presigned-put-url using two approaches:

1. Sending A form data: (**this is used with POST urls not PUT**)

- This actually add the `content-disposition` header to the final file as mentioned in the question.

2. Sending raw binary data (**recommended way and this how PUT url is used!**):

- The file was uploaded correctly, and does not include the `content-disposition` header.

Could you try sending the `PUT` request without using `formData` at all?

The ajax's `data` attribute should have a value of `file_data`, and the `content-type` while the signing the S3 URL and sending (ajax) should be `ContentType: 'binary/octet-stream'`.

If you need to use formData, check out S3's preSignedPost.

Comment: I quiet don't understand your answer, I have changed the content type but data attribute is where the content of the file goes or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, data attribute is where the content of the file goes. All i was trying to say is you should send the raw binary data of the file in that attribute, and not a formData object.

I have edited my answer.